# A question about a theorem in ONAG by Conway

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Does anyone here know about Conway's On numbers and games? Because I can't figure out what he does here on p18. It feels a bit like he's using the statement we want to prove

I will type the proof below:

Theorem 5. We have $y\geq z$ iff $x+y\geq x+z$.

Proof. If $x+y\geq x+z$, we cannot have

$$x+y^R\leq x+z\quad\text{or}\quad x+y\leq x+z^L$$

and so by induction we cannot have $y^R\leq z$ or $y\leq z^L$ so that $y\geq z$.

Now supposing $x+y\ngeq x+z$ we must have one of

$$x^R+y\leq x+z,\quad x+y^R\leq x+z,\quad x+y\leq x^L+z,\quad x+y\leq x+z^L,$$

and if we further suppose $y\geq z$, we deduce one of

\begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}\label{star}
x^R+y\leq x+y,\quad x+y^R\leq x+y,\quad x+z\leq x^L+z,\quad x+z\leq x+z^L,
\end{equation}

All of which imply contradictions by cancellation.

I think I don't understand the step \eqref{star} correctly, because I think it would require the theorem itself, but that may be wrong.

Comment: It's much better if you actually type out the formulae into the question, rather than providing an ephemeral link to an image.

Comment: As far as the question goes, I think he's just doing a typical inductive argument by contradiction - choose a least putative counter-example (so that all subgames satisfy the induction hypothesis) and show it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more readable and clear what I don't understand

Comment: Thanks.

A typical argument by contradiction in (structural) induction goes: suppose that the proposition does not hold.  Then take a _least_ counter-example X.  In our case, this means all _elements_ of X do satisfy the proposition.  Then prove that this implies a contradiction, hence the proposition holds for X, and as X was a least counterexample, the proposition must hold generally.

Here, he is proving $x+y\ngeq x+z$ implies $y\ngeq z$ (the converse direction) by contradiction.

Comment: I think I understand the structure of the proof, but to get from the first four inequalities to the latter four, I can't see an easy way without using the theorem itself. I do understand the rest though.

Comment: I also came up with a way to avoid what I think is using the theorem itself, but it doesn't involve the latter four inequalities at all. For the first one I did: $x^R+y\leq x+z$, so none of $x^R+y\geq (x+z)^R$, and thus $x^R+y \ngeq x^R+z$, but from $y\geq z$ and induction follows $x^R+y \geq x^R+z$, so a contradiction. The third one is similar. The second one implies by $y^R\leq z$ using the first part of the proof, but $y\geq z$ implies $y^R\nleq z$, so a contradiction. The fourth one is similar.